# Random rectangles 'missing' when rendering with optix + motion blur

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, motion-blur

When I render a scene that uses motion blur with optix, there are randomly rectangles/sections where it skips straight to the background. Its random and only exists in some frames, and does not appear when using cuda. The object it appears on (or near) has motion blur disabled.

Optix with Motion Blur:

[image: optix]

Optix without Motion Blur:

[image: optixnomb]

Cuda with Motion Blur

[image: cuda]

Comment: Hello and welcome, this sounds like a bug and should probably be reported. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For bug reports please see [Where to Report a Bug](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports)

Comment: I'm guessing it's an issue with Blender rather than something I've messed up then right?

Comment: Yes, it looks that way. Hard to say for sure, but that doesn't seem like desirable behaviour in any case